# Toggle elements view on buttons click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have different divs which all have the same class "textBox".

At the same time there should always just be one box displayed. For most Boxes there is a button on the bottom of my page which can be clicked and triggers
to make the box visible and hide the box which is already shown at this moment.

**Edit: Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8uvsq7ta/**

For this I have this JS-code:

```
$( "#gettingStartedButton" ).click( function () {

        if (! $( "#gettingStarted" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
            if ( $( "#extension" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                $( "#extension" ).fadeOut( function () {
                    $( "#gettingStarted" ).fadeIn();
                });
            }
            else if ( $( "#executingBox" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                $( "#executingBox" ).fadeOut( function () {
                    $( "#gettingStarted" ).fadeIn();
                });
            }
            else if ( $( "#feedback" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                $( "#feedback" ).fadeOut( function () {
                    $( "#gettingStarted" ).fadeIn();
                });
            }
            else if ( $( "#impressum" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                $( "#impressum" ).fadeOut( function () {
                    $( "#gettingStarted" ).fadeIn();
                });
            }
            else if ( $( "#registration" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                $( "#registration" ).fadeOut( function () {
                    $( "#gettingStarted" ).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            $( "#gettingStarted" ).fadeOut( function () {
                $( "#executingBox" ).fadeIn();
            });
        }
    });
```

The div boxes look like this:

```
<div id="gettingStarted" class="textBox">
test blabla
</div>

<div id="feedback" class="textBox">
test blabla
</div>

<div id="registration" class="textBox">
test blabla
</div>

<div id="impressum" class="textBox">
test blabla
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.textBox {
    diplay: none;
}
```

This Code checks if the box is already shown and if yes it checks **EVERY OTHER BOX** to get the one which is visible and then fade it out to afterwards fade the reffered box in.

My problem is, I need this part of code for **every** box. I think there should be a better way to accomplish this.

What I am searching is kind a method *openBox(id)* where I give the id of the box as paramete and it automatically detects all other boxes with the class parameter and detects which is already faded in, then fades this out to fade the box with the **id** in.

Sadly my javascript skills aren't that good, so I seek to find some advices or examples how to achieve this.

Thank you very much for every input you can give me.

Comment: We need the structure of your HTML to answer this effectively.

Comment: Can't understand what you trying to achieve. Also could you replicate similar demo in **Snippet** or [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @divy3993 Give me a sec, I try to build one.

Comment: @divy3993 and Atula: Please see my edit and the fiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $textBox = $(".textBox");               // get 'em all!
$textBox.eq(0).fadeIn();                    // FadeIn first one

$("[data-showid]").on("click", function(){  // Buttons click (Use data-* attribute!) 
  var $box = $("#"+ this.dataset.showid);   // Get the target box ID element
  $textBox.not($box).hide();                // Hide all bot targeted one
  $box.stop().fadeToggle();                 // FadeToggle target box
});
```

```css
.textBox{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="gettingStarted" class="textBox">getting started blabla</div>
<div id="feedback" class="textBox">feedback blabla</div>
<div id="impressum" class="textBox">impressum blabla</div>

<button data-showid="gettingStarted">GS</button>
<button data-showid="feedback">FB</button>
<button data-showid="impressum">Imp</button>
```

---

If you don't want the current box to toggle, than instead of `.fadeToggle()` use `.fadeIn()`.

http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/
https://api.jquery.com/data/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: @progNewbie added into my answer. So simply use `.fadeToggle()` instead of `.fadeIn()`

Answer (score 1):

With the addition of a `data-*` attribute on your button to link it to its content:

```
<button id="gettingStartedButton" data-link="gettingStarted">GS</button>
<button id="feedbackButton" data-link="feedback">FB</button>
<button id="impressumButton" data-link="impressum">Imp</button>
```

The javascript becomes very simple:

```
$( "#gettingStarted" ).fadeIn();

$('button').click(function(){
    var link = $(this).data('link');
    $('.textBox:visible').fadeOut(function(){
                    $('#' + link).fadeIn()
                });
})
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8uvsq7ta/2/

Comment: If you click fast the buttons you get a really weird result

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan dont fast click the buttons then!

Comment: Somehow if I click on a Button the new box fades in  before the other is fading out. And it would be awesome if the box would fade out when the button is clicked again.

Comment: @progNewbie - this is a direct port of your existing code, any problems that exist in this version exist in your current version.

Comment: @Jamiec: Sadly not. I have both fiddles open. On mine it is working fine. On yours not.

Comment: @progNewbie - my apologies - id not limited the `fadeOut` to only the `:visible` element - check update. They should now operate the same

Answer (score 1):

I did it using class. The HTML would be like :

```html
    <div class="textBox gettingStartedButton" style="display: none;"> 1 test blabla </div>
<div style="display: none;" id="feedback" class="textBox .gettingStartedButton gettingStartedButton"> 2 test blabla </div>
<div id="registration" class="textBox gettingStartedButton" style="display: block;">3 test blabla </div>
<div id="impressum" class="textBox"> 4 test blabla </div>
```

And use the code below. Keep any element visible at first. Then on click of that element it fades it out and fades the next element in. and adds the class "gettingStartedButton" to the visible element to run click event again.

```js
$( ".gettingStartedButton" ).on('click', function () {
  
  var visible_element  = $('.textBox:visible');
  visible_element.next().fadeIn();
  visible_element.next().removeClass('gettingStartedButton');
  visible_element.next().addClass('gettingStartedButton');
  visible_element.fadeOut();
  
});
```